# Wordpress shortcode repeating issue

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am creating a shortcode that grabs specific content from an url which i passed as a shortcode attribute. The problem happens when this a shortcode is used more than once on a single post. Then the second shortcode overrides the first one. Here is the code. Two values are displayed on the page both both are the same and are pulled from the second shortcode attribute. There should be two separate and different values.

Here is the shortcode code:

```
<?php
function grabUrl_func( $atts ) {

$url = $atts['url'];
$label = $atts['label'];
$productId = $atts['id'];


?>
<script>

    var urlFromSc = <?php echo json_encode($url) ?>;

    var buttonLabel = <?php echo json_encode($label) ?>;

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        jQuery.get(urlFromSc, function(response) {

            // grab product name

            var productName = jQuery(response).find('.product-name');

            var productNameContent = productName[1]['innerHTML'];

            jQuery('.g-title').append(productNameContent);


            // grab image

            var productImage = jQuery(response).find('.product-image-gallery');

            var productImageContent = productImage[0]['innerHTML'];

            jQuery('.g-image').append(productImageContent);

            jQuery('.g-image img').slice(1).remove();


            // grab price

            var productPrice = jQuery(response).find('.price-box');

            var productPriceContent = productPrice[0]['innerHTML'];

            jQuery('.g-price').append(productPriceContent);


            // grab rating

            var productRating = jQuery(response).find('.yotpo');

            var productRatingContent = productRating[0]['outerHTML'];

            var productId = jQuery(productRatingContent).attr('data-product-id');

            var link = jQuery('<a class="productLink" href="' + urlFromSc + '">' + buttonLabel + '</a>' );

            jQuery('.g-link').append(link);

        });
    });

</script>

<?php

$output =  '<div class="g-wrapper">'
    . '<div class="g-image"></div>'
    . '<div class="g-title"></div>'
    . '<div class="g-price"></div>'
    . '<div class="g-rating">'
    . '<div class="yotpo yotpo-main-widget" data-product-id="'.$productId.'"></div>'
    . '</div>'
    .'<div class="g-link"></div>'
    .'</div>';


return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'grabUrl', 'grabUrl_func' );

?>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The issue was occurring  because u are using  the same js variable name and also using the same html selector for both products.
Try to make your js variable name and  html selector name  unique for each product

Comment: may be you can use product id for variable and html selector to add uniqueness